# R doesn't list all files within folder

Tags: r, list

I use the following code to list al txt files within my folder:

Both work perfectly fine, but not all files are included in the list.

```
files <- list.files("C:/...", pattern="*.TXT")

files <- dir(path="C:/...", pattern=".TXT")
```

This is how my folder looks:
The first file is the only one included in the list (2700_2011_2012)
None of the other files is included.

I also tried changing the names of these files (e.g. without the [], but this does not change anything).

[image]

ddd

Comment: It appears that the patterns are case-sensitive. Does it solve your issue if you do `list.files(....,pattern="*.TXT",ignore.case=T)? Do the files appear in your list if you search without pattern?

Comment: +1 Heroka. Show your file suffixes and you'll see the issue. Also, the `*` is unnecessary; it quantifies what's before it, which is nothing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you use is case-sensitive. You can therefore fix the problem by setting `ignore.case` to `T`. Note the removal of the `*`, as @Alistaire is right; it's unnecessary.

```
list.files(......,pattern=".TXT",ignore.case=T)
```